# Hyperlinks in the body of a 303 response

Tags: web-services, http, rest, rfc2616

When doing 303 redirects after a POST, [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.4) mentions adding a hyperlink in the body of the response (i.e. the POST's 303 response body, not the response of the subsequent GET on newly created resource).

> 10.3.4 303 See Other
>
> The response to the request can be found under a different URI and
> SHOULD be retrieved using a GET method on that resource. This method
> exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to
> redirect the user agent to a selected resource. The new URI is not a
> substitute reference for the originally requested resource. The 303
> response MUST NOT be cached, but the response to the second
> (redirected) request might be cacheable.
>
> The different URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the
> response. Unless the request method was HEAD, **the entity of the
> response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the
> new URI(s).**

I have two questions about this:

1. Are there any implementations (browsers or otherwise) that make use of such a link in the body of a 303?
2. If adding a link to the body, what would the most appropriate link relationship be? `rel="self"`, `rel="alternate"` ? Neither seems totally appropriate. I realize there may not be a standard link relation for something like this, and if that is the case, so be it.

Comment: The "hyperlink" you're expected to add to the body is for the reader to read, not for the UA to process. So you'd want to use an <A HREF> for this purpose, not any sort of <LINK REL> tag.

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT- So basically, this isn't to provide any extra link information for the new resource, just as a fallback to display to the user in case their browser doesn't properly redirect on a 303?

Answer (score 1):

1) I believe all common browsers will display the response for a POST->303, although this may not be the case for GET (see http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc/httpredirects/#t303body)

Comment: Most browsers will display the response body on a 303 *if* they don't follow the redirection to the URI specified in the LOCATION header. In practice, 303 is pretty broadly supported, so the cases where this is a valuable practice are probably pretty rare.

Comment: Eric: see test case above -- IE doesn't appear to show the body on a GET response (it probably *does* on a POST response)